# Correct syntax for IF statement

Tags: javascript, syntax, if-statement

Can anyone tell me why this IF statement doesn't work, please? I'm using jQuery and Firebug but the latter is not giving me any useful information.

I'm simply attempting to reveal a "submit" button when all of the fields have been completed and the script runs every couple of seconds to check for input.

My code excerpt goes a little like this:

```
function checkForm(){
    var userName = $('#name').val();
    var userContent = $('#content').val();
    var userEmail = $('#email').val();

    // The following line shows me that the values for the fields are all getting picked up properly
    $('#report').html("userName: "+userName+"<br />userContent: "+userContent+"<br />userEmail: "+userEmail);

    // But the following line is throwing some kind of error
    if (userName == "" || userContent == "" || userEmail == ""){
        $('#update').slideDown();
    } else {
        $('#update').slideUp();
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#update').hide();
    setInterval('checkForm()' , 2000);

});
```

And my HTML...

```
<div id="report"></div>
<form id="submitfact">
  <div id="update">Update Database</div>
  <label><input id="name" name="name" type="text" value="" /><span>Fact submitter's name</span></label>
  <label><input id="email" name="email" type="text" value="" /><span>Fact submitter e-mail address</span></label>
  <label class="content"><span>Fact text</span><br /><textarea id="content" name="content"></textarea></label>
</form>
```

**Edit...**

I apologise if people think I'm wasting their time by not providing the error message - but Firebug simply isn't giving me anything useful - if it was I'd be posting it here. I am a reasonably experienced php programmer but fairly new to jQuery so I admit I am still getting to grips with both writing the language and debugging it. I'd like to post a screen shot of Firebug's response but, as a new user, I am not allowed... all I am getting is a "red error circle/yellow play triangle" icon in the line numbers column ("script" tab) on the line I've shown above... there is nothing else unless you can tell me where else to look other than the "script" and "console" panels?

**Another edit...**

Well, I got it fixed by taking a look at Cristoph's suggestion. It's basically the same solution but instead of calling it as a function I put it "inline". I'm not entirely sure what the difference between the two techniques is or whether it's simply a local issue I was having but my new jQuery looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#submitfact').keyup(function(){
        var userName = $('#name').val();
        var userContent = $('#content').val();
        var userEmail = $('#email').val();

        $('#report').html(userName + "<br />" + userContent + "<br />" +  userEmail);

        if (userName == "" || userContent == "" || userEmail == ""){
            $('#update').slideUp();
        } else {
            $('#update').slideDown();
        }
    });
});
```

I will have a look through your other comments to see if I can streamline it at all but at least I have a working baseline now! Thanks for your time, everyone :)

Comment: Are they indeed empty strings, or `null`?  Also, I would have this check done when an input is modified, not on a timer.

Comment: If a line is throwing an error, do you not think it is beneficial to post the error? Also, Moo-Juice is right, why are you doing this on a timer?!

Comment: "doesn't work" is not a problem description. What a waste of everybody's time.

Comment: I would give you the error if I knew what it was - Firebug is simply hanging on that line without elaborating on the issue... this is why I'm asking you guys :) I will edit the code to check on keyup instead of a timer - thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: BTW, Moo-Juice - how would I check if they were null instead of empty strings?

Comment: I tested your code and worked fine, please paste the error you're getting

Comment: With @coletch answer. Not that I think it'll help you...

Comment: Where is the submit button in your html you're wanting to show on form completion?

Comment: Tried your code here, http://jsfiddle.net/ffJhE/6/ , it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, is it really throwing an error, or is it simply not working?

From how i understand your code, your if condition should be:

```
if (!userName === "" && !userContent === "" && !userEmail === ""){
    // show
    $('#update').slideDown();
} else {
    // hide
    $('#update').slideUp();
}
```

Second: doing this with a timer is a bad idea.

Introducing an eventhandler to check once an inputvalue changed is far better:

```
$("input").change(function(){

  // if all inputs are filled, show Button, else hide it

});
```

P.S.
advanced insight into Javascript: an empty string is considered "falsy", thus
`username === ""` could be written as `!username`. Note however, that `undefined`, `null`, `false`, `0`  and `NaN`are also considered "falsy"! THis means, you can't distinguish them. For this reason i prefer `username === ""` ( [note the === !](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators)  )

Comment: Thanks Christoph - Simply changing my code to match your logic n the first instance made no difference, however rewriting my code as pr your second suggestion did the trick. I have amended my original post accordingly. Thanks! :)

Comment: it is - I've edited my original post to show the functioning script... not sure what has made the difference, TBH - hopefully I'll figure this out when I get better at jQuery :)

Comment: You should accept an answer to show the other users your problem has been solved.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your evaluation to this:

```
if (!userName  || !userContent  || !userEmail){
    $('#update').slideDown();
} else {
    $('#update').slideUp();
}
```

Comment: You could simplify it further with a little math: `if (!(userName && userContent && userEmail)) {`